# How do I specify multiple database schemas in Diesel?

Tags: rust, database-schema, rust-diesel

How to specify multiple schemas in Diesel ORM (Rust). I desire to have several models specified into different schema according to their domain categories. I used a similar solution with hibernate and JPA in Java( you specify the default schema in the global configuration and the rest of the schema on each entity modal).

This is what I can currently configure in diesel.toml, but it is limited to a single schema only.

```
[print_schema]
file = "src/schema.rs"
schema = "shema-name"
```

Comment: I guess this is related to your issue: https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/issues/1728. It's currently open.

Comment: are you solving this problem? @geobudex

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the schema field in [print_schema] is for specifying only the default schema(If no value is provided, the public schema will be searched). For tables in a schema other than the default, the table name should be given as "schema_name.table_name". More is stated [here](http://diesel.rs/guides/configuring-diesel-cli.html)